# Unexpected token: name (stateCheck) (line: 23, col: 4)

Tags: javascript

I got a little script That i try to minify I got an error message:

> Unexpected token: name (stateCheck) (line: 23, col: 4)

Can you tell me my mistake?

```
let stateCheck = setInterval(() => {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    clearInterval(stateCheck);
   if (getCookie('subscribe') !=1){
    [~]
    }
  }
}, 100);
```

Comment: You are using `stateCheck ` before it got initialised I think. What do you expect `stateCheck ` to be inside your anonymous function?

Comment: `[~]` - what's this?

Comment: I don't think this piece of code is the problem if didn't break because of `[~]`, normally that should throw a syntax error